# Does Levene's test assume separate samples?

Tags: variance, assumptions, levenes-test

I want to run Levene's test to test the equality of variances between a full sample and a sub-sample. I can't find anything about Levene's test that states whether this would violate the assumptions of the test. In other words, given the null hypothesis that $\mathrm{Var}(X_{1}) = \mathrm{Var}(X_{2})$, does Levene's test require that $X_{1} \cap X_{2} = \varnothing$?

Comment: The usual reason for testing equality of variance this way is to run an ANOVA/regression. This shouldn't be done with the whole group vs. a subgroup, it should be done with one subgroup vs. another.

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm looking for a method to compare the variance of the whole group to each subgroup one-by-one. Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is not to do this. Why do you want to? You should almost surely compare the variances of all the subgroups, instead.